# Retry tests with Android Test Orchestrator and Gradle?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am running flaky instrumental tests and I am curious if there is any option to retry a failed test again. I only came across third party frameworks and maven solutions, but I want a Gradle + native Android Test Orchestrator solution. I am running the test on a CI environment and I hate checking flaky tests, so I want a CLI solution.

Answer (score -1):

Custom Gradle tasks and test annotations can achieve what you want.

1. Create a Custom Gradle Task:
   Start by creating a custom Gradle task that will run your instrumental tests. You can do this in your project's build.gradle file.

```
task runInstrumentalTests(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'adb', 'shell', 'am', 'instrument', '-w', '-r', 'your.package.name/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}
```

2. Configure Test Retry Logic:
   Implement test retry logic using annotations in your instrumental test classes. You can use JUnit's @RetryTest annotation to mark specific tests that you want to retry.

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
import androidx.test.filters.FlakyTest;
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;
import androidx.test.filters.MediumTest;
import androidx.test.filters.SmallTest;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyInstrumentedTest {

    @Test
    @FlakyTest
    @RetryTest(maxRetries = 3)
    public void myFlakyTest() {
        // Test logic here
    }
}
```

3. Implement Test Retry Logic: Create a custom test runner or rule to detect and retry test failures based on annotations, implementing the necessary retry logic.

```
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;

public class RetryTestRule implements TestRule {

    private int maxRetries;

    public RetryTestRule(int maxRetries) {
        this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
    }

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return statement(base, description);
    }

    private Statement statement(final Statement base, final Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                Throwable caughtThrowable = null;

                for (int i = 0; i <= maxRetries; i++) {
                    try {
                        base.evaluate();
                        return;
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        caughtThrowable = t;
                        System.err.println(description.getDisplayName() + ": run " + (i + 1) + " failed");
                    }
                }
                System.err.println(description.getDisplayName() + ": giving up after " + maxRetries + " failures");
                throw caughtThrowable;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

4. Apply Retry Logic to Tests:

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
import androidx.test.filters.FlakyTest;
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;
import androidx.test.filters.MediumTest;
import androidx.test.filters.SmallTest;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) //Apply the custom test rule to your test classes in your instrumental test suite.
public class MyInstrumentedTest {

    @Rule
    public RetryTestRule retryTestRule = new RetryTestRule(3);

    @Test
    @FlakyTest
    public void myFlakyTest() {
        // Test logic here
    }
}
```

5. Run tests via Gradle

```
./gradlew runInstrumentalTests
```

Reference:

https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html